# SSL enforced but receiving some parts of the site are not using SSL warning

Tags: apache, https, security-certificate

I had been trying to enforce SSL for my site but although the SSL certificate is signed properly by networksolutions, each time the pages are loaded it still displays an SSl warning in browser warning:

> "Some parts of the site are not using SSL"

In I.E, it's even worse if you hit "No I don't want to view unsecured part of the page": the site does not display properly (as it blocks some of the widgets).

*Screenshot:*

[image: screenshot of ssl warnings in browser]

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure all of the files on that page are called over HTTPS. This includes:

- Images
- Stylesheets
- JavaScripts
- Objects (i.e. Flash)
- Frames/Iframes
- Files from other websites (Facebook, Twitter, etc)

I see some CSS that is not loaded over SSL that probably is causing your issue.